# function that calls to author functions (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a map that takes a function that calls other functions, and a list of functions - so here is what I've put in:

```
    def function1():
      return 3

    def function2():
      return 4

    def List_Of_Functions(My_Function):
      return My_Function

    print(list(map(List_Of_Functions, [function1, function2])))
```

but this is what I get in the result:

```
[<function function1 at 0x7f5e6797a620>, <function function2 at 0x7f5e6797a730>]
```

I'm new to Python so any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'author functions'?

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Maybe a misspelling of "other functions"?

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the code you are calling any of the functions `function1` or `function2`.

I think what you are after is by amending the middle method to become:

```
  def List_Of_Functions(My_Function):
     return My_Function()
```

Without the parentheses after the `My_Function`, it's just passing a reference to the function and doing nothing with it.
Adding the parentheses - it's calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `function1()` and `function2()` in the last statement

```
def function1():
    return 3

def function2():
    return 4

def List_Of_Functions(My_Function):
    return My_Function

print(list(map(List_Of_Functions, [function1(), function2()])))
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained what's different, and why it matters. Otherwise the reader has to go through the code character by character to find what you changed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I explained but lost in the edit. You can see the revision history